# Possible to see pending changes (actual changes, not just status) for others?

Tags: tfvc

I'm thinking not, but is it possible to pull up changes others are currently working on? I know they can shelve, but just thinking if someone (with proper security) could actually access a read only copy of their pending changes w/o them having to shelve that would be a super cool and useful feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pending changes" only exist on an individual's machine, so no, you can't see other peoples' changes unless they somehow put them on the server, either in the form of a check-in or in the form of a shelveset.